# Transfer file to another PC using C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have to transfer file to another PC in which I have created a `shared` folder. I am able to access this shared folder since the another PC is connected via ***LAN*** cable.

Now I want to transfer a file to that `shared` folder using C#. I am following a tutorial from [**this link**](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/443588/simple-csharp-ftp-class).

**Code MWE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FileTransferApplication
{
    class ftp
    {
        private string host = null;
        private string user = null;
        private string pass = null;
        private System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        private System.Net.FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        private System.IO.Stream ftpStream = null;
        private int bufferSize = 2048;

        static void Main()
        {
            ftp ftpClient = new ftp(@"ftp://X.X.0.20/", "dst username", "dst pc password");

            /* Upload a File */
            ftpClient.upload(@"shared\test.txt", "E:/SampleFile2.txt");
            ftpClient = null;
        }

        /* Construct Object */
        public ftp(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

        /* Upload File */
        public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
        {

            try
            {

                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
                System.IO.FileStream localFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(localFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
                try
                {

                    while (bytesSent != 0)
                    {

                        ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                        bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                localFileStream.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

**PS:** I am using Windows-7.

**UPDATE-1:** Actually I have shared the folder for test purpose since I am still in the learning phase to transfer the file. But my actual requirement is to transfer the file to a server/PC using IP address, username and Password.

**Question:** I am running a Filezilla ftp server on my 2nd PC. I have already created a `User` alognwith its `password`. I have added the `shared` folder in the directories which can be shared. Now, I am getting an error

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.
```

for the line `ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();`

Comment: without being able to re-create the issue I don't see how this is answerable. Your best placed to solve this problem, not us

Comment: is the destination PC enable ftp?

Comment: *"IP address, username and Password"* is pretty vague. You have to have some file transfer server (FTP, SFTP, or other) installed on the machine for that. Have you?

Comment: yes, I am running Filezila server on the destination PC. Kindly have a look at my updated `Question`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sorry, I did not understand how the code is not MWE. The above code compiles without any error. I have written `@"ftp://X.X.0.20/", "dst username", "dst pc password"` in the code here but in the actually code, I am passing the correct IP, username and password. Please let me know what else should I add to the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I have already checked that answer but none of the suggestion worked for me.

Comment: Can you connect to the FTP server from your local machine using a standalone FTP client (like WinSCP or FileZilla)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that it's a shared folder, just use [`File.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).  FTP is way overkill for this simple task.

Comment: Actually I have shared the folder for test purpose since I am still in the learning phase to transfer the file. But my actual requirement is to transfer the file to a server/PC using IP address, username and Password.